# Proper Face Mask Detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, machine-learning, keras

So I have been trying my hands on python script to detect Mask on a face. There are a ton of repos with the code for the same but they were simply detecting whether if a person is wearing a mask or not.
I want my script to also detect whether if the mask is been properly worn or no, for example mask worn but not covering the mouth or say mask worn but not covering the nose.
Below is the code i used for training data -

```
# import the necessary packages
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV2
from tensorflow.keras.layers import AveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from imutils import paths
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

# initialize the initial learning rate, number of epochs to train for,
# and batch size
INIT_LR = 1e-4
EPOCHS = 20
BS = 32

DIRECTORY = r"D:\mask\dataset"
CATEGORIES = ["with_mask", "without_mask"]

# grab the list of images in our dataset directory, then initialize
# the list of data (i.e., images) and class images
print("[INFO] loading images...")

data = []
labels = []

for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DIRECTORY, category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_path = os.path.join(path, img)
        image = load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
        image = img_to_array(image)
        image = preprocess_input(image)

        data.append(image)
        labels.append(category)

# perform one-hot encoding on the labels
lb = LabelBinarizer()
labels = lb.fit_transform(labels)
labels = to_categorical(labels)

data = np.array(data, dtype="float32")
labels = np.array(labels)

(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels,
    test_size=0.20, stratify=labels, random_state=42)

# construct the training image generator for data augmentation
aug = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=20,
    zoom_range=0.15,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.15,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode="nearest")

# load the MobileNetV2 network, ensuring the head FC layer sets are
# left off
baseModel = MobileNetV2(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,
    input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))

# construct the head of the model that will be placed on top of the
# the base model
headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(7, 7))(headModel)
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(128, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(headModel)

# place the head FC model on top of the base model (this will become
# the actual model we will train)
model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)

# loop over all layers in the base model and freeze them so they will
# *not* be updated during the first training process
for layer in baseModel.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# compile our model
print("[INFO] compiling model...")
opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
    metrics=["accuracy"])

# train the head of the network
print("[INFO] training head...")
H = model.fit(
    aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
    steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
    validation_data=(testX, testY),
    validation_steps=len(testX) // BS,
    epochs=EPOCHS)

# make predictions on the testing set
print("[INFO] evaluating network...")
predIdxs = model.predict(testX, batch_size=BS)

# for each image in the testing set we need to find the index of the
# label with corresponding largest predicted probability
predIdxs = np.argmax(predIdxs, axis=1)

# show a nicely formatted classification report
print(classification_report(testY.argmax(axis=1), predIdxs,
    target_names=lb.classes_))

# serialize the model to disk
print("[INFO] saving mask detector model...")
model.save("mask_detector.model", save_format="h5")

# plot the training loss and accuracy
N = EPOCHS
plt.style.use("ggplot")
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["loss"], label="train_loss")
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["val_loss"], label="val_loss")
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["accuracy"], label="train_acc")
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["val_accuracy"], label="val_acc")
plt.title("Training Loss and Accuracy")
plt.xlabel("Epoch #")
plt.ylabel("Loss/Accuracy")
plt.legend(loc="lower left")
plt.savefig("plot.png")
```

and below is the code for detecting face mask -

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import os
def detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet):
# grab the dimensions of the frame and then construct a blob
# from it
(h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, (224, 224),
    (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))

# pass the blob through the network and obtain the face detections
faceNet.setInput(blob)
detections = faceNet.forward()
print(detections.shape)

# initialize our list of faces, their corresponding locations,
# and the list of predictions from our face mask network
faces = []
locs = []
preds = []

# loop over the detections
for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
    # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with
    # the detection
    confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

    # filter out weak detections by ensuring the confidence is
    # greater than the minimum confidence
    if confidence > 0.5:
        # compute the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding box for
        # the object
        box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

        # ensure the bounding boxes fall within the dimensions of
        # the frame
        (startX, startY) = (max(0, startX), max(0, startY))
        (endX, endY) = (min(w - 1, endX), min(h - 1, endY))

        # extract the face ROI, convert it from BGR to RGB channel
        # ordering, resize it to 224x224, and preprocess it
        face = frame[startY:endY, startX:endX]
        face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        face = cv2.resize(face, (224, 224))
        face = img_to_array(face)
        face = preprocess_input(face)

        # add the face and bounding boxes to their respective
        # lists
        faces.append(face)
        locs.append((startX, startY, endX, endY))

# only make a predictions if at least one face was detected
if len(faces) > 0:
    # for faster inference we'll make batch predictions on *all*
    # faces at the same time rather than one-by-one predictions
    # in the above `for` loop
    faces = np.array(faces, dtype="float32")
    preds = maskNet.predict(faces, batch_size=32)

# return a 2-tuple of the face locations and their corresponding
# locations
return (locs, preds)

# load our serialized face detector model from disk
prototxtPath = r"face_detector\deploy.prototxt"
weightsPath = r"face_detector\res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"
faceNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)

# load the face mask detector model from disk
maskNet = load_model("mask_detector.model")

# initialize the video stream
print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()

# loop over the frames from the video stream
while True:
# grab the frame from the threaded video stream and resize it
# to have a maximum width of 400 pixels
 frame = vs.read()
 frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)

# detect faces in the frame and determine if they are wearing a
# face mask or not
(locs, preds) = detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet)

# loop over the detected face locations and their corresponding
# locations
for (box, pred) in zip(locs, preds):
    # unpack the bounding box and predictions
    (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box
    (mask, withoutMask) = pred

    # determine the class label and color we'll use to draw
    # the bounding box and text
    label = "Mask" if mask > withoutMask else "No Mask"
    color = (0, 255, 0) if label == "Mask" else (0, 0, 255)

    # include the probability in the label
    label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, max(mask, withoutMask) * 100)

    # display the label and bounding box rectangle on the output
    # frame
    cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, startY - 10),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, color, 2)
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), color, 2)

# show the output frame
cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

# if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
if key == ord("q"):
    break

# do a bit of cleanup
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

I am using trained model which is successfully able to detect mask on live stream on multiple people as well. All I need is to figure out how detect whether if the mask is worn properly or not.
what are the workarounds for this. What changes has to be done in the code?

P.S. - I am a novice when it comes to ML.

Any suggestions or help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a workaround for this. You simply have to collect more data where the mask is worn unproperly and increase the numbers of class in your model:
From only two categories ["with_mask", "without_mask"] to ["with_mask", "without_mask","not_wearing_properly]

Collect the data for the third class then retrain your model. Change this line:

```
headModel = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(headModel)
```

To this:

```
headModel = Dense(3, activation="softmax")(headModel)
```

Because now you have 3 class instead of 2

Comment: Hi tried to the method suggested by you, but I am running into some error. i am getting this -

Answer (score 0):

Hi i tried the method suggested by Minh but i am running into some errors.
Here's what I am getting.

```
Warning (from warnings module):
File "C:\Users\Ayus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site- 
packages\PIL\Image.py", line 952
"Palette images with Transparency expressed in bytes should be "
UserWarning: Palette images with Transparency expressed in bytes should be converted 
to RGBA images
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\mask\train_mask_detector.py", line 59, in <module>
test_size=0.20, stratify=labels, random_state=42)
File "C:\Users\Ayush\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site- 
packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 2152, in train_test_split
train, test = next(cv.split(X=arrays[0], y=stratify))
File "C:\Users\Ayush\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site- 
packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 1746, in split
y = check_array(y, ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
File "C:\Users\Ayush\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site- 
packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 72, in inner_f
return f(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Ayush\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site- 
packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 641, in check_array
% (array.ndim, estimator_name))
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

How to get rid of this error. I have posted the source code above, the script for training data.